# Combine OR query with AND query in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to filter documents according to some filters categories: 

[image]

It is the classical case where the values should be taken in an OR condition within the same category and in an AND query between different categories.
I use the following code to build the QueryFn for Cloud Firestore (without any sort of optimization yet):

```
const queryResults: Observable<Place[]>[] = [];
queryFilter.typeFilter.forEach(filter => {
queryResults.push(
    this.afs
        .collection<Place>(
            this.PLACE_COLLECTION,
            ref => ref.orderBy('placeName').where('type', '==', filter)
        )
        .valueChanges()
    );
});

queryFilter.starsFilter.forEach(filter => {
    queryResults.push(
        this.afs
            .collection<Place>(
                this.PLACE_COLLECTION,
                ref => ref.orderBy('placeName').where('rate', '==', filter) 
            )
            .valueChanges()
    );
});

// TODO: it should filter AND over the OR results

const resultNum = queryResults.length;

if (resultNum === 1) {
    return queryResults[0].pipe(shareReplay(1));
} else if (resultNum > 1) {
    const firstObs = queryResults[0];
    const clone = [...queryResults]; 
    clone.splice(0, 1);
    return firstObs.pipe(
        combineLatest(...clone, (...arrays) => arrays.reduce((acc: any, array: any) => [...acc, ...array], [])),
        shareReplay(1)
    );
}

return of([]);
```

Here how I build the filters and invoke the method above:

```
 combineLatest(
        this.formGroup.get('typeFilters').valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null)),
        this.formGroup.get('starsFilters').valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null))
    )
        .pipe(
            filter(values => !(values[0] === null && values[1] === null)),
            switchMap(([types, stars]) => {
                const typeFilter: string[] = [];
                const starsFilter: number[] = [];

                if (types) {
                    types.map((v: string, idx: number) => {
                        if (v) {
                            typeFilter.push(this.placeTypelabels[idx]);
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (stars) {
                    stars.map((v: string, idx: number) => {
                        if (v) {
                            starsFilter.push(this.ratinglabels[idx].value);
                        }
                    });
                }

                const filters: FilterModel = { typeFilter: typeFilter, starsFilter: starsFilter };
                return this.placeService.filterPlaces(filters);
            }),
            takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        )
        .subscribe(p => {
            return (this.places = p);
        });
```

Individually the results are correctly retrieved, but they are not in an AND between the two result sets. Is it possible to achieve this in Firestore, without the use of Elastic Search or similar solutions?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI from the Firebase YouTube channel.

Comment: As far as I can see, you have N query snapshots of two types: filtered by type, and filtered by rate. Is the last block of code (in the `else if (resultNum > 1)` meant to perform the AND?

Comment: @Frank The N query snapshots are to collect all the OR queries (as Firestore does not allow logical OR yet). The AND part is still missing. The part within  resultNum > 1 condition is to pack all the observables into a unique result, so that I can subscribe to it and provide as array of my DTOs in the component.

Comment: Ah, got it. So you still need to loop over all results sets and only select documents that match are in every result set. Since you're using AngularFirestore, I assume there is some RxJs-fu to do this. Unfortunately my RxJs-fu is mediocre at best, so hopefully somebody else can answer.

Comment: @Frank: I execute an individual query for each OR condition and then "pack" each returning Observable into a unique one, so that I do not to have to loop over the dataset on the client side. However I would need to combine those 2 result sets into an AND condition on Firestore if possible. Otherwise I would need to "build" the AND condition at the client side, but I do not like too much this as I would like to make all the queries on Firestore. Made it simple: "How can I implement my filtering case (with OR and AND) in Firestore?". Is there a way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some more trials I was able to achieve my goal, even if the result is more than sub-optimal.

I edited the code building the AND/OR queries in the following way:

```
filterPlaces(queryFilter: FilterModel): Observable<Place[]> {
    const queryResults: Observable<Place[]>[] = [];

    const typeFilter = queryFilter && queryFilter.typeFilter ? queryFilter.typeFilter : [];
    const starsFilter = queryFilter && queryFilter.starsFilter ? queryFilter.starsFilter : [];

    // No filter items selected
    if (typeFilter.length < 1 && starsFilter.length < 1) {
        return this.queryPlaces(null);
    }

    if (typeFilter.length > 0 && starsFilter.length > 0) {
        // Multiple filters internally in OR and among them in AND
        starsFilter.forEach(starFilter => {
            // FIXME: The number of Calls grows with the filters used!!
            typeFilter.forEach(filter => {
                queryResults.push(
                    this.afs
                        .collection<Place>(this.PLACE_COLLECTION, ref =>
                            ref
                                .orderBy('placeName')
                                .where('type', '==', filter)
                                .where('rate', '==', starFilter)
                        )
                        .valueChanges()
                );
            });
        });
    } else {
        // Individual OR Cases
        if (typeFilter.length > 0) {
            typeFilter.forEach(filter => {
                queryResults.push(
                    this.afs.collection<Place>(this.PLACE_COLLECTION, ref => ref.orderBy('placeName').where('type', '==', filter)).valueChanges()
                );
            });
        }

        if (starsFilter.length > 0) {
            starsFilter.forEach(filter => {
                queryResults.push(
                    this.afs.collection<Place>(this.PLACE_COLLECTION, ref => ref.orderBy('placeName').where('rate', '==', filter)).valueChanges()
                );
            });
        }
    }

    return combineLatest(...queryResults, (...arrays) => arrays.reduce((acc: any, array: any) => [...acc, ...array], [])).pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
```

If the user selects at least a value in both filters, I iterate over the selected items of one filter and I add them as further AND condition to each item selected in the second filter.

**In this way I can execute queries like: "Get (Hotel OR Bar) AND (1* OR 2* OR 5*)"** for example.

However this approach is suited only for small filters as the number of calls grows with the number of filter and their selected elements.
I leave this code here as it might be of inspiration to someone else. I am curious though if anyone can suggest how to answer my original question or to improve the current solution.